# generate xlsx from local rdl file

Tags: excel-2007, rdl

I have an rdl file that I am downloading off a sharepoint site. Is there any way to convert an .rdl file to excel 2007? I want to read the report data in excel rather than on the share point site.

Comment: Something like http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255234.aspx ?

Answer (score 1):

You can convert RDL file to Excel 2007 file with **[Aspose.Cells for Reporting Services](http://www.aspose.com/reporting-services/excel-component.aspx)** API ans this API now supports SQL Server 2014 also.